# sub domains that access common folders

Tags: php, directory, subdomain

I've two sub-domains : 1) root/mobile where mobile points to m.mydomain.com  2)root/beta where  beta points to beta.mydomain.com

But I want both the sub domains to access some common folders that are under root like root/images

Comment: Is it on a GNU/Linux? If so, can you not just symbolic link the dirs you need?

Comment: If you check out the commands on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link you may find a simple solution to your question.

Comment: Wait. Is there a problem accessing `root/images` from the two web roots? Or is `images` something you want to be web accessible? Just looking for some clarity on the issue.

Comment: i want root/images to be accessed from two differnet sub domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access files in a directory higher than the one you are in with `..`. For example, let's say we're in `root/mobile/index.php` and we want to access `root/lib/include.php`. You could include the file with `include('../lib/include.php');`

Note: This assumes that the "common files" you are trying to access are both accessible from this user account.

Comment: well as I've said root/mobile where mobile points to m.mydomain.com which makes "mobile" its root. So my question is how can I go beyond root & access say root/lib/include.php

Comment: Are they in separate filesystems?

Comment: This worked. I dont know wht went wrong in the first place. I tried now it worked. gr8!

Answer (score -1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php you could use it to have a PHP file that you place in both root/mobile and root/beta. It could then read in images from root/images.

Comment: How? It looks like they were looking for a way to use PHP to load images from a common directory on two different sub doamins. Loading the images into PHP and then using PHP to show it would accomplish this.

Comment: @someoneHuman this is not the answer Im looking for. Images was just an example. That common files cud be anything say class files

Comment: Your code explains how to make an image resource from a JPG file and then it "can read in images from root/images". That doesn't explain HOW to read in those images from root/images, all you've done is repeat what he said he needed done.